# if $1<f(x)<2$ for $0<x<1$ and $f$ is continuous at $x = 0$, what can you say about $f(0)$?

Tags: calculus, continuity

if $1<f(x)<2$ for $0<x<1$ and $f$ is continuous at $x = 0$, what can you say about $f(0)$?
I'm a Calc I student and have no idea where to even begin with this.

Comment: Can you make a guess?

Comment: I have tried everything my teacher has shown and covered on continuity and the continuity rules, and so far I believe that it doesn't break any rules of the continuity checklist. Not sure why it seems these continuity problems are so much harder than derivatives, or how they apply in a practical sense.

Comment: There are three possibilities for $f(0)$: either $f(0)>1$, or $f(0)=1$, or $f(0)<1$. Try to draw a *continuous* graph for each of the three cases and see which one seems impossible.

Comment: What properties of $f$ could you be expected figure out?

Answer (score 1):

Begin by writing down the implications of $f$ being continuous at $x=0$. Continuity at $x=0$ implies there exists a real number $a$ such that

$$ \lim_{x \to 0^+} f(x) = \lim_{x \to 0^-} f(x) = f(0) = a $$

we also know $1<f(x)<2$ for $0<x<1$, so

$$ 1 \le \lim_{x \to 0^+} f(x) \le 2 $$

By substitution we have

$$ 1 \le f(0) \le 2 $$

Comment: $f(x) = x+1$ and $f(x) = 2-x$ satisfy the hypotheses and so we can have $f(0) \in [1,2]$.